# validated_data returns empty dictionary on update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am building a backend system like Udemy, in this Cart API I am trying to update a cartitem object (a student want to add another course instead of this one) so I want to change the course in the cartitem and change the total_price of the cart. What happens is that when I update the course field it returns HTTP_200_OK response status but the body of the response is the JSON object of the exact same object before updating and the object is not updated

models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    student = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cart')
    total_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(
        Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
class CartItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CartItem.objects.filter(cart_id=self.kwargs['cart_pk'])

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'PUT':
            return UpdateCartItemSerializer
        elif self.request.method == 'POST':
            return CreateCartItemSerializer
        else:
            return CartItemSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {
            'cart_id': self.kwargs['cart_pk']
        }
```

serializers.py

```
class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    student_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_student_id(self, cart_item):
        return Cart.objects.filter(id=self.context['cart_id'])[0].student_id

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['id', 'student_id', 'course_id']


class CreateCartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = CartItem.objects.get(cart_id=validated_data['cart_id'],
                course_id=validated_data['course_id'])

        try:
            return instance
        except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
            instance = CartItem.objects.create(**validated_data)
            instance.save()

        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['id', 'course_id']


class UpdateCartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print(instance.__dict__, validated_data)
        current_course_id = instance.course_id
        new_course_id = validated_data.get('course_id', instance.course_id)

        if current_course_id != new_course_id:
            condition = CartItem.objects\
                .filter(cart_id=instance.cart_id) \
                .filter(course_id=new_course_id) \
                .exists()

            if not condition:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    CartItem.objects \
                        .filter(id=instance.id) \
                        .update(course_id=new_course_id)

                    old_price = Course.objects \
                        .filter(id=current_course_id)[0].price

                    new_price = Course.objects \
                        .filter(id=new_course_id)[0].price

                    current_cart_price = Cart.objects \
                        .filter(id=instance.cart_id)[0].total_price

                    current_cart_price -= old_price
                    current_cart_price += new_price

                    Course.objects \
                        .filter(id=new_course_id) \
                        .update(total_price=current_cart_price)

                    instance.save()
            else:
                CartItem.objects.filter(id=instance.id).delete()
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['id', 'course_id']
        read_only_fields = ('id', )
```

Before making the PUT request
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykfwh.png)
After making the PUT request
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4wq7.png)

**Bonus question:** Why the HTML Form of the serializer isn't recognizing my fields?[HTML Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZsXC.png)

I tried to comment everything to reach the position of the error but in vain.

Comment: In `UpdateCartItemSerializer`. After updating the `course ID` and calculating the new `total price`, you are calling `instance.save()` again. it is unnecessary because the changes have already been made in the database through the `update` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is here. If I understand correctly your code in a quick look, you expect that at this point

```
Course.objects.filter(id=new_course_id).update(total_price=current_cart_price)
instance.save()
```

the object `instance` and the object `Course.objects.filter(id=new_course_id)` are the same, and after using `update` both have the same values.

If my understanding of what you try to do is correctly, you should not use this logic. `update` make a query directly against the database, `instance` is not refreshed and the `save` method of the model is no called.

So, when you return `instance` at the end of the method, you are returning and old versión of the model.

So, use something like:

```
Course.objects.filter(id=new_course_id).update(total_price=current_cart_price)
# instance.save() # not needed
instance.refresh_from_db()
```

or

```
# Course.objects.filter(id=new_course_id).update(total_price=current_cart_price)
instance.total_price = current_cart_price
instance.save() # not needed
```